# Create a valid system path from Poweshell script which read by system.io.file.readalltext()

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I am creating a asp website which will run PowerShell scripts and provide the results on web page.

My issue is now, I have one script which is returning a full path of a Log file. This returned path I am passing into System.IO.File.ReadAllText(). But I am getting Invalid characters exception at runtime.

Example:

ABC.PS1

```
param(
    [String]$computer
)
$Logfile = "C:\Scripts\ABC_$($computer)_$(Get-Date -f "dd-MM-yyy_hh-mm-ss").log"
$Logfile | Out-String
```

.aspx.cs

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            PowerShellInstance.AddCommand(@"C:\Scripts\ABC.ps1");
            PowerShellInstance.Commands.AddParameter("computer", ServerNameTB.Text);
            var results = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                var builder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var psObject in results)
                {
                    builder.Append(psObject.BaseObject.ToString());
                }
                String resultPath = builder.ToString();
                //Exception invalid characters
                diskCeanUpResult.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(resultPath); 
                }
            }
```

How do I convert the returned path so that it can be access by File.ReadAllText()

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by adding `.TrimEnd('\r', '\n')`

```
String resultPath = builder.ToString().TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
diskCeanUpResult.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(resultPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your own answer works, but you can make the `.TrimEnd()` call unnecessary by tweaking your `*.ps1` script:

```
param(
    [String]$computer
)
# Output the string directly.
"C:\Scripts\ABC_$($computer)_$(Get-Date -f "dd-MM-yyy_hh-mm-ss").log"
```

You don't need `Out-String` to output strings, and if you do use it, it appends an extra newline (CRLF on Windows) to the output.
That is, a single-line input string will turn into a two-line output string (the input string with a trailing newline).